# Javascript/JSP iterate through Datatable and count occurrencies

Tags: javascript, jsp, datatable

I have a Datatable that gets filtered on two columns: the first one is the project, and the second is the platform. Each project can be executed on each platform. I need to iterate through all the rows of that Datatable and get a statistic of how many times a project is executed on a platform.
Here's part of my code where I have the table:

```html
<p id="date_filter">
  <input type="text" id="datepicker_from" class="form-control date-range-filter" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" placeholder="From:">
  <input type="text" id="datepicker_to" class="form-control date-range-filter" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" placeholder="To:">
</p>


<button onClick="calculateStatistics()">Click!</button>

<select class='filter' id="select">
  <option value="">All softwares</option>
  <option value="">software1</option>
  <option value="">software2</option>
  <option value="">software3</option>
  <option value="">software4</option>
</select>

<select class='filter' id="selectWindows">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="">winXp</option>
  <option value="">win7</option>
  <option value="">winVista</option>
  <option value="">win10</option>
</select>

<table id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>software name</th>
      <th>windows version</th>
      <th>CreatedDate</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>


  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 1</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 1</td>
      <td>winXp</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 2</td>
      <td>win7</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 3</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 3</td>
      <td>winXp</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 4</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 2</td>
      <td>winVista</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 4</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 4</td>
      <td>win7</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 1</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 4</td>
      <td>winXp</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    function calculateStatistics() {

   var selectPlatformCheck = document.getElementById("selectWindows");
   var selectPlatformSelected = selectPlatformCheck.options[selectPlatformCheck.selectedIndex].value;
      //projects
      var software1 = "";
      var software2 = "";
      var software3 = "";
      var software4 = "";

      //platforms
      var win10 = 0;
      var winXp = 0;
      var win7 = 0;
      var winVista = 0;

      
      if(selectPlatformSelected !="") {
          for(var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++){
            if(selectPlatformSelected != "") {
                if(selectPlatformSelected == "win10"){
                    win10++;
                }
                else if(selectPlatformSelected == "winXp"){
                    winXp++; 
                }
                else if(selectPlatformSelected == "win7" ){
                    win7++; 
                }
                else{
                    winVista++; 
                }
            }
          }
      }
      
  }
  
  </script>
```

Clicking on the button "Click" I need to create a new tab on which I'm printing how many time a project runs on a platform, for instance:

```
software1 runs: 
2 times on win10
1 time on winXp

software2 runs:
1 time on win7
1 time on winVista

software3 runs:
1 time on win10
1 time on winXp

software4 runs:
2 times on win10
1 time on win7
1 time on winXp
```

How could I do that in javascript/JSP?
here's a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/feanor93/becgq7fL/64/

Also, is there a way to print those statistics in a fancy way?
Thank you very much

EDIT: here's my javascript function that is returning constantly 0's:

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: I have added my script

Comment: Please update the snippet I made with your script in a [mcve] - click edit then scroll down cut your script and click edit above snippet

Comment: Done, it is now reproducible but it won't work because it is bugged

Comment: In code is there, on JSfiddle is there, on that snippet is now showing, but the code is in there. I don't know why it isn't showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a start

```js
function calculateStatistics() {
  const selectPlatformSelected = document.getElementById("selectWindows").value;
  //projects
  var software1 = "";
  var software2 = "";
  var software3 = "";
  var software4 = "";


  const platforms = {
    win10: 0,
    winXp: 0,
    win7: 0,
    winVista: 0
  };
  [...document.querySelectorAll("#datatable tbody tr")].forEach(row => {
    const platform = row.cells[2].textContent;
    platforms[platform]++;
  })
  document.getElementById("stats").innerHTML = selectPlatformSelected ? 
  selectPlatformSelected+": "+platforms[selectPlatformSelected] : 
  Object.keys(platforms).map(platform => platform+": "+platforms[platform]).join("<br/>");
  
}
```

```html
<p id="date_filter">
  <input type="text" id="datepicker_from" class="form-control date-range-filter" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" placeholder="From:">
  <input type="text" id="datepicker_to" class="form-control date-range-filter" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" placeholder="To:">
</p>

<button onClick="calculateStatistics()">Click!</button>
<div id="stats"></div>

<select class='filter' id="select">
  <option value="">All softwares</option>
  <option value="">software1</option>
  <option value="">software2</option>
  <option value="">software3</option>
  <option value="">software4</option>
</select>

<select class='filter' id="selectWindows">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="win10">win10</option>
  <option value="win7">win7</option>
  <option value="winXp">winXp</option>
  <option value="winVista">winVista</option>
</select>

<table id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>software name</th>
      <th>windows version</th>
      <th>CreatedDate</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>


  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 1</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 1</td>
      <td>winXp</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 2</td>
      <td>win7</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 3</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 3</td>
      <td>winXp</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 4</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 2</td>
      <td>winVista</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 4</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 4</td>
      <td>win7</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 1</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 4</td>
      <td>winXp</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That is very nice, thanks! But it is not selecting on the entire datatable, only on the page I'm on. Is there a way to modify that code in order to count the occurrences on every page of the datatable?

Comment: No. Then you need to add ajax/pagination

Comment: ok, I need to implement a way to use Ajax then. Thank you very much